# web service field missing in results

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I'm using VB.Net 2013 developing a Windows app.

I'm sending an object with fields to an external web service.  One of the fields is not coming through for our client, even though I can print the value of the object's field in the Immediate Window when I use a breakpoint on the line of code that loads the object through the web service.

All other fields with values are received by the client, but this one field is not.  The field is an Integer field, while the other fields are all String.

Background: The field that is missing was originally a String field when we first started this project.  The application ran twice every day for ten years with no problems.  Our client upgraded their back end system and the web service, and in the interim they changed the datatype for the field in question from String to Integer.  We are sending an Integer value.  I proved this using VARTYPE in the Immediate Window.

I have the latest version of the web service as my web reference.

The client claims there are two other vendors who use the same system and the value comes through for them.

If the field & value are there at the moment we're sending the object through the web service, and I can't do anything to the object after it's been launched, how do I figure out why the client isn't receiving that field?  Are there any tools I can use to capture the object myself?  Could there be something at the client's end that is doing this?

Any help would be really appreciated.